# The temperature dependence of the electron-hole (or particle-hole) continuum

Tags: condensed-matter

In the theory of the electron gas, the particle-hole pairs are possible elementary excitations. I would like to know how the temperature T affects the particle-hole continuum which defines the domain where the imaginary part of the density-density response function (or Lindhard function) is different from zero. I need to understand it in order to calculate the Lindhard function at finite temperature.